# Make a checkbox conditionally format it's own cell + the cell to its immediate right

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The first image is how it is using basic conditional formatting. The first image is how it is using basic conditional formatting. The second image is how I want it to automatically conditionally format, created manually for demonstration. Any help is appreciated, thank you.
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Considering A3 as the first cell of the conditional formatting, you can use OFFSET to look at the cell at the left. IFERROR is used for cells in A column because there's no cell at their left:

```
=OR(A3=TRUE,IFERROR(OFFSET(A3,0,-1)=TRUE,))
```

Comment: Thank you - where would I paste this? If I paste it in the cell adjacent to a checkbox, I can't write in the cell anymore. Much appreciated.

Comment: Select the range (for example in A3:L) and apply at the whole range simultaneously, in conditional formatting as a custom formula